# Loop of array image Control in VBA Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In PowerPoint VBA,
I try to put 10 images named

```
image1
image2
image3
etc.
```

in an array of image controls.
So I want to do something like this:

```
for i=1 to 10
    Set Image(i).Picture = LoadPicture(sPath & "\kkk\" & i & ".jpg")
next i
```

But it doesn't work so far.

Comment: So is what you've tried working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Please edit your question with the error(s) you get.

Comment: Are you adding picture to the Slide or a UserForm (tag:=powerpoint-vba)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are loading 10 pictures into a UserForm Images named "`Image#`", below should work fine.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        With Me.Controls("Image" & i)
            Set .Picture = LoadPicture(sPath & "\kkk\" & i & ".jpg")
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```